Docker Compose not synchronising file changes in volume
Reposting from here as I don't quite understand how the "solution" works.
Symptom:
As reported here:
I mount my local files into the container for development. My docker-compose.yml file is as follows:
version: '3.7'
services:
  node:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    image: node
    ports:
      - "4000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    working_dir: /code

when I run the Next JS server in a container, it will initially load fine, but any changes made afterwards will not be shown.
This is same as my observation as well.
Answers:
There has been discussion on the issues of running docker in Windows 10 Pro, but I'm hosting in Linux for Linux, and the "solution" mentioned nothing about Windows either.
Solution:
The reported working "solution" is:
version: '3.7'
services:
  node:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    image: node
    ports:
      - "4000:3000"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /code
    working_dir: /code

This, to my knowledge, would be the same as what used by OP, i.e.:
    volumes:
      - .:/code

I.e., I think the question of why "docker Compose not synchronising file changes in volume" was not clearly answered. And neither of the following pages:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678042/named-docker-volume-not-updating-using-docker-compose
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251094/i-want-to-share-code-content-across-several-containers-using-docker-compose-volu/44265470
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958573/docker-compose-recommended-way-to-use-data-containers

My case:
I have a php site hosted on nginx:
version: '3.7'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:8081"
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:delegated
            - ./app:/app:delegated
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: PHP.Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app:delegated
        restart: always

This is my observation:

I do docker compose up
Then ^-C to stop it
Update code in host,
Re- do / start docker compose up
Check the modified volume-mounted file within docker compose container,
The file stays the same, as before the change.


This would be easier to diagnose with a complete, reproducible example. At first glance it doesn't make any sense -- there is no "synchronization" between the volume mounted in the container and the source directory on the host; this is a bind mount which means the two locations are the same directory.

In the step, "Check the modified volume-mounted file within docker compose container", which volume are you checking? You have two bind mounts in your configuration (one for ./app and one for ./nginx). Are they both exhibiting the same behavior? What commands are you running to check the files?

You said you're running on Linux; is there are particular reason you're using the :delegated flag on your bind mounts? Does the behavior change if you omit it?

"is there are particular reason you're using the :delegated flag on your bind mounts", yeah, I suspect that it's the culprit as well. Thanks for pointing it out. It's a "known-to-be-working" file that I borrowed, and I was not planning to change anything unless there's a reason. Let me try...

hmm..., removing all :delegated from docker-compose.yml and my site can’t be reached any more -- it refused to connect. This is an inherited site, and I don't even know where to start the troubleshooting... I just rebuild everything with docker compose up --build, but my site still can’t be reached, even locally with curl localhost.
